# REST results undefined

Tags: rest, app

I am executing this code, but am getting the d.results = undefined:

```
'use strict';
$(function () {
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        var message = $("#message");
        message.text("There are " + data.d.results.length + " items in this list");
        messa.append("<br/>");
        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
            message.append(value.Title);
            message.append("<br/>");

        });

    });

    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
        var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
        alert(message);

    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change URL `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items`

Comment: Please add it as answer so I could mark it.

Comment: Richard: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to get items you should change the URL as follows

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items
```